# How to make viewpager items larger than screen?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, screen

I have viewPager's views children which should be larger than the screen. How can I make this work, and keep the "pagination effect"?

Comment: ViewPager can contains multiple Page with the help of ViewPagerAdapter

Comment: I do know that, my question is how to have items that can be larger than the screen?